# Why do I find that OLS linear regression is robust against colinearity?

Tags: regression, least-squares, multicollinearity

As per the textbook, OLS should fail when using colinear covariates. On their [LinearRegression() documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares), sklearn states:

> When features are correlated and the columns of the design matrix
> have an approximately linear dependence, the design matrix becomes
> close to singular and as a result, the least-squares estimate becomes
> highly sensitive to random errors in the observed target, producing a
> large variance. This situation of multicollinearity can arise, for
> example, when data are collected without an experimental design.

Why is it, then, that I have no problem doing a linear fit with perfectly colinear features? See below.

Note **I am not talking about coefficients interpretations** (into which colinearity obviously throws a monkey wrench), but simply the idea that colinearity + OLS leads to matrix singularity and error message.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = (np.arange(0, 100, 1) + np.random.normal(1,1,100))
X = np.stack((x,x)).T

y = np.arange(0,200,2)

print(f"Example of X data: {X[:5]}")
print()
print(f"Example of y data: {y[:5]}")
print()

print(f"Correlation between the two features of X: {pearsonr(x, x)[0]}")
print()

model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(X, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,5))

ax.scatter(x, y, label="truth")
ax.plot(x, model.predict(X), label="OLS")
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("y")

plt.show()

print(f"Regression intercept: {model.intercept_}")
print(f"Regression coefficients: {model.coef_}")
```

[image]

Comment: There's no contradiction: multicollinearity translates to uncertainty in the *coefficients,* not in the fitted values.  Your source unfortunately is ambiguous about this: by "the least-squares estimate" it means the coefficients *only,* not the fit.

Comment: There IS a contradiction: by definition, OLS should not be able to produce a result with an input with perfectly colinear features, as OLS requires to compute the inverse of the Gram matrix of X, which is singular when X contains linearly dependent columns (and thus, non-invertible).

Comment: You don't have perfectly correlated features.

Comment: That's not a definition.  I'm afraid it's an appeal to a couple of misconceptions.  The *definition* is in the very name "ordinary least squares:" one minimizes the sum of squares of residuals.  That problem *always* has a solution--but it cannot always be obtained by inverting a matrix.  (The *generalized inverse* accomplishes this.) In the presence of collinearity, OLS has a space of solutions: but, *by definition,* they all minimize the sum of squared residuals and, because that objective is convex, the *fit* to the data is always the same for all solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with OLS is not that a solution is not achievable, but that the solution is not unique. For a model matrix, $X$, the quadratic form $X^TX$ needs to be invertible. The OLS coefficient is given by $\hat{\beta} = \left(X^TX \right)^{-1}X^Ty$. When $X$ is not of full rank, then a pseudo-inverse can be calculated instead. Whereas an inverse requires $I = M^{-1}M$, a pseudo-inverse is any matrix that has the property $M = M^T M^{-1}M$, but a pseudo-inverse is not unique. It looks like the particular expression in scipy is to "split" the beta between the two covariates. However, there are downstream issues of prediction, inference, and extrapolation that aren't as sensitive when the $X$ is not rank deficient.

Comment: With the posted code X.shape returns (100,2) while y.shape returns (100,). This is a multivariate regression alright.

Comment: Ah. I gave up Python for R before scipy came out, so I'm *that* rusty. I see the arange function for Y is a length 100 vector by 2s from 0 to 100. What `scipy` has done then is perform - and not tell you - a pseudoinverse. The solution is not unique and for some reason, it has split the coefficient value between the two X. Shame scipy doesn't warn you about this - R sets extra coefficients to NA - search for pseudoinverse in this SE to get more background. In other words, it's still a problem, but it doesn't mean a solution can't be found.

Comment: Makes sense. I started looking into scipy's code and there seems to be a few addenda to basic OLS in case the input is not "proper." Thanks for pointing me in that direction AdamO!

Comment: Subsequent question: non-colinearity amongst covariates is often stated to be one of OLS assumptions. Is it really? If so, why build an implementation of OLS that "works" (i.e. outputs a result) in that particular case?